# FontSizer Script is there a cleaner way?

Tags: jquery, cookies, code-cleanup

I use Jquery-Cookie to store the fontsize and if the link is active.
Everything works like i want. But I'm new in Jquery and i want to ask you guys if there is a cleaner and faster way to do this.

So the active link is underline and i also store this in the cookie.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("body").css("font-size", $.cookie('font-size'));
    var underline = $.cookie('active');
    $(underline).addClass('activefontsize');

    $(".small").click(function () {
        $('.activefontsize').removeClass('activefontsize')
        $(this).addClass('activefontsize')
        $("body").css("font-size", "11px");
        $.cookie('font-size', '11px');
        $.cookie('active', '.small');
    });

    $(".normal").click(function () {
        $('.activefontsize').removeClass('activefontsize')
        $(this).addClass('activefontsize')
        $("body").css("font-size", "12px");
        $.cookie('font-size', '12px');
        $.cookie('active', '.normal');
    });

    $(".big").click(function () {
        $('.activefontsize').removeClass('activefontsize')
        $(this).addClass('activefontsize')
        $("body").css("font-size", "13px");
        $.cookie('font-size', '13px');
        $.cookie('active', '.big');
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

I suppose this is as clean as it gets:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("body").css("font-size", $.cookie('font-size'));
    var underline = $.cookie('active');
    $(underline).addClass('activefontsize');

    $(".small, .normal, .big").click(function () {
        $('.activefontsize').removeClass('activefontsize')
        $(this).addClass('activefontsize');
        var fontsize=0;
        var myClass=$(this).attr('class');
        switch(myClass){
            case 'small':
                fontsize=11;
                break;
            case 'normal':
                fontsize=12;
                break;
            case 'big':
                fontsize=13;
                break;
        }
        $("body").css("font-size", fontsize+"px");
        $.cookie('font-size', fontsize+'px');
        $.cookie('active', '.'+myClass);
    });

});
```

Comment: Sorry, not working for me. When i use your code i get in my console. 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word. It's the line with var class=$(this).class();

Comment: change the variable `class` to `myClass` and you're good to go

Comment: I will check it tomorrow. And will let you know. Thx for your help.

Comment: So i try but now i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'class'"

Comment: ah, stupid me, there's no `class()` function it is `.attr('class')`, fixed it, check the answer again